# How to remove foreign characters from Web Page?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, .htaccess, content-type

I have html files in books folder. Trying to load html files using jQuery load method in another html page, but it shows foreign characters such as  � .

Code:

```
PageContentURL = "books/" + bookTitle + "/book_" + bookTitle;

$("#container").load(PageContentURL);
```

URL to work : 
http://ashapanchal.com/TheBibleScholarHTML/chaptercontent.html?bid=2&btitle=Eastons%20Bible%20Dictionary&cid=4&ctitle=D&spi=186&epi=220&tpi=186

Why is it so? How to remove foreign characters? I have set charset and tried many solution available online.

Comment: Sounds like an ecoding problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your response headers on `Apache` server .

What you have now , is just `'Content-Type: text/html'` header for `.html` files.
So you need to create `.htaccess` file (if not already exists) and add this lines:

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
    Header unset Content-Type
    Header append Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

could u try this code :))

```
str.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
```

if u want to try

```
<input type='button' value='click' id="click"/>

<input type='text' value='' id="testtt"/>


$(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
     var str=   $('#testtt').val();
        var newvalue =   str.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
          alert(newvalue);
        });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from chaptercontent.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The problem was that the main page was encoded using utf-8 while the page you were including was iso-8859-1. Because the main page was utf-8 it interpret the included page as utf-8 too.